# Customizing JPanel with Sea Glass Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, look-and-feel, seaglass

I have a `JFrame` and a `JPanel`. I have added my `JPanel` onto my `JFrame`. I am using Sea Glass Look and Feel. My `JPanel` has a title and a border created through the following code : `panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Titled Panel"));`

The problem is when I run my program with Sea Glass Look and Feel, the border does not show; but when I disable it the border will show as I want it.
Here is my code:

```
import com.seaglasslookandfeel.*;

public class SeaGlassLF extends JFrame {

    SeaGlassLF() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 300));
    this.setSize(300, 300);
    this.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
    this.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(200, 200));
    panel.add(new javax.swing.JButton("Click Me"));
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Titled Panel"));

    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager
                        .setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SeaGlassLF sg = new SeaGlassLF();

        }
    });
   }
  }
```

**Qsn.** What could be the cause and how do we solve this?

Below are the images showing the output of the program.

1. With **NO** Sea Glass Look and Feel(Border available -pointed by the red arrow).

[image]

2. With Sea Glass Look and Feel(no border available).

[image]

Comment: plus one for SSCCE/MCVE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- in Seaglas L&F is required to override possition for [titlePossition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html#TitledBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29), -
- e.g. code line

.

```
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, 
     "Titled Panel", TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, 
     TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)));
```

generated me (by using seaglasslookandfeel-0.1.7.3.jar) this

.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a pretty brute-force way:

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("TitledBorder.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```

But I'm sure (I hope!) there are more elegant solutions.

Every look and feel can set these values. I guess the authors of this look and feel have decided that lined borders don't fit with their style, so have hidden them.